# Automate the process of How to backup Bitlocker recovery information in AD

Tags: powershell

I am trying to automate this process.  By running the command below, I get the information I am looking for.  The numerical password ID which is ID: {DFB478E6-8B3F-4DCA-9576-C1905B49C71E}

> manage-bde -protectors -get c:

I need to then take this value {DFB478E6-8B3F-4DCA-9576-C1905B49C71E} and place it in the same command with a different syntax.

```
manage-bde -protectors -adbackup c: -id {DFB478E6-8B3F-4DCA-9576-C1905B49C71E}
```

The problem is I need to strip it out of the info presented by the program at the command prompt.

I need to script this so I can import this in to a MDT 2013 task sequence.  Any direction would be appreciated.

This will be run on the local machine while I am imaging it.  The full output is below.

```
manage-bde -protectors -get c:

Example:

Bitlocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 6.1.7600
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Volume C: Old Win7
All Key Protectors
External Key:
  ID: {F12ADB2E-22D5-4420-980C-851407E9EB30}
  External Key File Name:
    F12ADB2E-22D5-4420-980C-851407E9EB30.BEK

Numerical Password:
  ID: {DFB478E6-8B3F-4DCA-9576-C1905B49C71E}
  Password:
    224631-534171-438834-445973-130867-430507-680922-709896

TPM And PIN:
  ID: {EBAFC4D6-D044-4AFB-84E3-26E435067AA5}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the dedicated CmdLet. From an elevated Windows PowerShell console, use the `Get-BitlockerVolume` function, select `-MountPoint C`, and choose the KeyProtector property:

```
(Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint C).KeyProtector
```

All the Bitlocker Cmdlets :

```
get-command -Noun *bitlocker*

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Add-BitLockerKeyProtector                          1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Backup-BitLockerKeyProtector                       1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Clear-BitLockerAutoUnlock                          1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Disable-BitLocker                                  1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Disable-BitLockerAutoUnlock                        1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Enable-BitLocker                                   1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Enable-BitLockerAutoUnlock                         1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Get-BitLockerVolume                                1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Lock-BitLocker                                     1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Remove-BitLockerKeyProtector                       1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Resume-BitLocker                                   1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Suspend-BitLocker                                  1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Unlock-BitLocker                                   1.0.0.0    BitLocker
```

---

So if the returned text is a raw text string you can do :

```
$text = & manage-bde -protectors -get c:
$reg = [regex]'.*(\{.*?\}).*'
$a = $reg.Matches($text)
```

So you've got your 3 UUID

```
$a[0].captures.groups[1].value
$a[1].captures.groups[1].value
$a[2].captures.groups[1].value
```

---

if the returned text is a multi line text string you can do :

```
$text = & manage-bde -protectors -get c:
$text = $text | Out-String
$reg = [regex]'.*(\{.*?\}).*'
$a = $reg.Matches($text)
```

So you've got your 3 UUID

```
$a[0].captures.groups[1].value
$a[1].captures.groups[1].value
$a[2].captures.groups[1].value
```

Comment: Thanks for the info @JP but these are Windows 7 machines that are only running powershell v2.0

Comment: @Ken, I try to adapt my answer using regular expression.

Comment: @JP thanks for input again!  When I run any of the three $a[1]... commands, it tells me they are null.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I could somehow strip out just what I need and do something like :          & manage-bde -protectors c: -adbackup -id {DFB478E6-8B3F-4DCA-9576-C1905B49C71E}

Comment: @Ken, I made a mistake in my indexes and add a solution in the case the return of the execution is not a raw string but a string array.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @JP !  that is exactly what I needed.