# Script to get Bitlocker protector info then backup to AD

Tags: powershell

OK. So Here is exactly what I am looking to do via a Powershell script. I am trying to help my team out by scripting this and by no means am I an expert with this topic, quite the contrary actually. This is why I turn to all of you experts.

So I have a list of the machine names in AD that do not have BitLocker Recovery information listed in each computers AD Account.she

What I would like to do by a PowerShell script is the following:

1. Ping each machine name from a computers.txt file to determine if the machine is online
2. If the machine name pings as active: 
   a. run the CMD line cmd: manage-bde -CN [computername] -protectors -get C:
   which will return a Numerical password in the form of:

Numerical Password:
      ID: {########-####-####-####-############}

b. take the numeric password and back it up to AD using the command:
manage-bde -CN [computer name] -protectors -adbackup c: -id {numeric password}

I have created a script which takes a list of computer names from the computers.txt file and runs a test-connection on each, outputting "pinging"/"not pinging" to an output .txt file. Being new to scripting, I am having trouble with the 2nd two parts. Here is what I have so far:

```
$ServerName = Get-Content "c:\Computers.txt"  
foreach ($Server in $ServerName) {  
  if (test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 2 -Quiet ) {   
    "$Server is Pinging "  
  } else {  
    "$Server not pinging"  
  }                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell has cmdlets for this.

```
Get-Command -Name '*bitlocker*' | Format-Table -AutoSize

CommandType Name                              Version      Source                                           
----------- ----                              -------      ------                                           
Function    Add-BitLockerKeyProtector         1.0.0.0      BitLocker                                        
Function    Backup-BitLockerKeyProtector      1.0.0.0      BitLocker                                        
Function    Backup-BitLockerKeys              0.0          ModuleLibrary                                    
Function    BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector 1.0.0.0      BitLocker                                        
Function    Clear-BitLockerAutoUnlock         1.0.0.0      BitLocker                                        
Function    Disable-BitLocker                 1.0.0.0      BitLocker                                        
Function    Disable-BitLockerAutoUnlock       1.0.0.0      BitLocker                                        
Function    Enable-BitLocker                  1.0.0.0      BitLocker                                        
Function    Enable-BitLockerAutoUnlock        1.0.0.0      BitLocker                                        
Function    Get-BitLockerVolume               1.0.0.0      BitLocker                                        
Function    Lock-BitLocker                    1.0.0.0      BitLocker                                        
Function    Remove-BitLockerKeyProtector      1.0.0.0      BitLocker                                        
Function    Resume-BitLocker                  1.0.0.0      BitLocker                                        
Function    Suspend-BitLocker                 1.0.0.0      BitLocker                                        
Function    Unlock-BitLocker                  1.0.0.0      BitLocker                                        
Application BitLockerDeviceEncryption.exe     10.0.17134.1 C:\WINDOWS\system32\BitLockerDeviceEncryption.exe
Application BitLockerWizard.exe               10.0.17134.1 C:\WINDOWS\system32\BitLockerWizard.exe          
Application BitLockerWizardElev.exe           10.0.17134.1 C:\WINDOWS\system32\BitLockerWizardElev.exe
```

[Enable-Bit​Locker](http://%20%20%20%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/enable-bitlocker?view=win10-ps)
Enables BitLocker Drive Encryption for a volume.

```
Example 1: Enable BitLocker

$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString "1234" -AsPlainText -Force
Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:" -EncryptionMethod Aes256 -UsedSpaceOnly -Pin $SecureString -TPMandPinProtector

This example enables BitLocker for a specified drive using the TPM and a PIN for key protector.
```

[Backup-Bit​Locker​Key​Protector](http://%20%20%20%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/backup-bitlockerkeyprotector?view=win10-ps)
Saves a key protector for a BitLocker volume in AD DS.

```
Example 1: Save a key protector for a volume

$BLV = Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint "C:"
Backup-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint "C:" -KeyProtectorId $BLV.KeyProtector[1].KeyProtectorId

This example saves a key protector for a specified BitLocker volume.
```

[This question could be seen very similar to this Q&A discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712179/automate-the-process-of-how-to-backup-bitlocker-recovery-information-in-ad)

Automate the process of How to backup Bitlocker recovery information in AD

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This is super helpful and gives me a great foundation to learn even more!